# Add array of lines in a file using shell script

Tags: bash

I am trying to add multiple lines into a file. For that I used array of lines and trying to append the array into a file. My shell script look as follows-

```
 Instance_Home='/home/ritu/Downloads/OHS_LINUX_SCDs'
 Http_ConfFile=$Instance_Home/httpd.conf

 array[0] = "LimitRequestBody 512000"
 array[1] = "LimitRequestFields 40"
 array[2] = "LimitRequestFieldsize 100"
 array[3] = "LimitRequestline 500"
 echo ${array[*]}  >> $Instance_Home/httpd.conf
```

Expected result would be:

```
  ># cat /home/ritu/Downloads/OHS_LINUX_SCDs/httpd.conf

   LimitRequestBody 512000
   LimitRequestFields 40
   LimitRequestFieldsize 100
   LimitRequestline 500
```

But its throwing error like-

```
 Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: 13: Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: array[0]: not found
 Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: 14: Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: array[1]: not found
 Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: 15: Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: array[2]: not found
 Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: 16: Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: array[3]: not found
 Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: 18: Apply-OHS-L-2.7.sh: Bad substitution
```

Can't find what is wrong with this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `${array[@]}` instead of `${array[*]}` will solve the problem.

After your comment found out something else. Remove the spaces before and after the "=" sign. so `array[0]="123"` instead of `array[0] = "123"`.

Comment: Used ${array[@]} >> $Instance_Home/httpd.conf in the script but still getting same output as stated in question...

Comment: @Ritu I found the problem remove spaces before and after "=" so `array[0]="123"` instead of `array[0]  =  "123" `